# registry edit remove pinch and zoom on surface pro 3

Tags: windows-registry, microsoft-surface-pro-3

My daughter has CP and her hand enables the pinch zoom - is there a way to disable pinch zoom on the surface pro 3?

I have contacted microsoft multiple times, they state you can disable touch altogether which is not what I want to accomplish - she can get around the system very well

Comment: Why did somebody vote to close a question about a Windows touch device?  **This question is 100% on topic.**

Comment: Agreed. The Surface Pro 3 is a conventional Windows device and is clearly on-topic for Super User.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1078418/disable-pinch-to-zoom-on-a-windows-10-pc-with-normal-non-precision-touchpad

Answer (score 3):

This is interesting it's one that I've battled with on my two Windows 8 tablets and an all-in-one PC.

I found a fix for one of my tablets which would be worth a go:

- Click on Start ORB
- Type settings in the search
- Click on Mouse (which will bringup a mouse control panel in desktop
  mode)
- There will be a tab at the top most likely far right which references
  the touch screen
- Under this the touchscreen should be listed and give the ability to
  edit the settings for that device
- You can untick the pinch to zoom here

This appeared on one of my tablets but not on the other, let me know how you get on.

Comment: Unfortunately the touchscreen option does not exist on the surface pro 3

Comment: What is the last tab on the mouse settings is it hardware?

Comment: Is there not an event you can listen to like ctrl+mouswheel on chrome <45? Why does SP3 ignroe viewport settings?